# How to unmock an exception using Mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, exception, junit, mockito, spring-boot-test

I am trying to mock a function for various results. First, I mocked it for throwing an exception as follows:

`Mockito.when(ClassName.methodName(Matchers.any(), Matchers.any())).thenThrow(new ExceptionName());`

Now, I want to mock for a case when it return some output. So, I am trying as follows:

```
    Mockito.when(ClassName.methodName(Matchers.any(), Matchers.any())).thenReturn(output);
```

But it is throwing exception(Maybe because I have already mocked it to throw exception)

How should I unmock it, so that I can use it to give proper output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define behavior of mock for multiple calls as follows:

```
when(ClassName.methodName(any(),any()))
                .thenThrow(RuntimeException.class)
                .thenReturn(output)
                .thenCallRealMethod();
```

When your mock is called in service for the first time it will be thrown RuntimeException, for the second will be returned `output`, for the third will be called a real method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Mockito.reset()` to clear any mocking setup you have done on a particular mock (for example `Mockito.reset(someMock)`).

NOTE: It is usually better to make your tests smaller so you don't need to use `reset`. If you are using `@MockBean`, the mocks are reset after each test method by default. This default behaviour can be changed via the [reset](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html#reset--) parameter on the annotation.

Comment: Is there any other way in which we can reset only for a particular functions? Because I have mocked for other functions as well and this method might reset the mocks for the other methods as well.

Comment: Are you manually creating the mock instances? Or are you using the `@Mock` annotation? Or are you using `@MockBean` annotation?

Comment: I am using @MockBean annotation for creating the instances

Comment: `Mockito.reset()` fixed the issue ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a nested class using @Nested and move all your exception methods into it and create a separate setup for those functions only. This structure will help you segregate all the similar methods